# Why are (S)pinor representations *restrictions* of Clifford algebra representations?

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, mathematical-physics, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

Firstly, just to clarify my notation:

Let $Cl(V,q)$ denote the Clifford Algebra of a quadratic vector space $(V,q)$ and denote by $Cl(V,q)_{0\vert 1}$ the even/odd part in the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading of $Cl(V,q) = Cl(V,q)_0 \oplus Cl(V,q)_1$ of the Clifford-algebra.

Now for the subgroups $Pin(V,q) \subset Cl(V,q)$ and $Spin(V,q)\subset Cl(V,q)_0$ is is defined:

> A *pinor representation* is the restriction of an irreducible
>   representation of $Cl(V,q)$ onto $Pin(V,q)$. Similary a *spinor
>   representation* is the restriction of an irreducible representation of
>   $Cl(V,q)_0$ onto $Spin(V,q)$.

My **question** is: What is the reason in defining pinor/spinor-representations as the **restrictions of Clifford algebra representations**, rather then just as usual **group-representations** of the groups themselves?

Remark: "Physical" explanations (as: 'The so defined spinor fields wouldn't behave like spinors, since...') are also very welcome.

Comment: Where is your definition taken from? It would be helpful to add some reference.

Comment: It is taken from the lecture notes to [this course on spin geometry](https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/Spin/).

Comment: Relevant [link](http://www.eleceng.adelaide.edu.au/personal/dabbott/publications/IAS_chappell2016.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that there is a matter of terminology involved here.

When speaking about "*spinors*" we do not exactly mean the elements of the group $Spin(V,q)$ but rather the elements of special vector spaces upon which Clifford algebras act. In other words, the terminology spinors imply the elements of some [specific](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1683765/195021)  (Clifford algebra, Pauli matrices etc )-module.

On the other hand, you are right in the fact that these spinor representations are not the only representations of the $Spin(V,q)$ group. In fact these ones are  faithful. They are the ones obtained by restriction from the action of the Clifford algebra on the spinor space (spinor module). You can have a more detailed look [here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/ag/ga/teaching/seminare/ws0304/repr.pdf) for the definitions and the elementary properties implied (look mainly at the definitions and the proposition of the first page).

Comment: The pointer to the faithfulness actually answers my question pretty well, thanks!